# SparkSQL with Hive data source will do a full table scan for head()?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

When executing this:
`select * from table_name limit 5` in Hive shell, it takes 18 seconds to complete;

But when I write this in SparkSQL:

```
table = hiveCtx.sql("select * from table_name")
print table.head()
```

It is the same when I write

```
table = hiveCtx.sql("select * from table_name limit 5")
```

or

```
table = hiveCtx.table("table_name")
```

I see it resulting in a HiveTableScan, which takes more than 30 minutes to complete before actually executing `head()`, since the table is really big.

I'm wondering whether it is an appropriate behavior of SparkSQL? Or I made something wrong?

I'm using Spark 1.6.3.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this same "problem" before and a colleague told me this

> The best optimization is that Spark can limit each executor to N and then limit to N on the final result set

So, your job is distributed onto numerous executors, each one attempting to execute your query as-is, and then the data is returned to the `head()` call, limiting the dataset and a later time, thus causing the delay.

By that logic, I would imagine that the `limit 5` should perform quicker than a pure `select *` or `table("table_name")`

I personally haven't looked into the process enough to know if that is true, but it makes sense when you think about executors may die, or some may only query a subset of data that doesn't reach the specified limit, in which case  those results need to be joined with another result set.

Comment: Thank you! So the execution logic for the same SQL is different between SparkSQL and Hive?

Comment: Not necessarily. For example, you can limit Spark to 1 executor, but that defeats the purpose of distributed processing